# Can't set static IP in router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

I was looking to set a static IP for my Raspberry Pi in my new router. However, when I set everything up I get this error

> MAC address "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" has already applied for IP address from DHCP server.

The router is from a company named Tenda and for some reason has no model name or number marked anywhere on it or in its firmware. My previous router was also from the same company but static IP worked without any problems on it.

My guess is to disable the DHCP server option on the router, but I don't wanna mess anything up on there hence I am seeking help.

Comment: You can delete the lease for the RPi in your router (dunno if you have that option since you can't give the router's model), disable DHCP server until you enforce the IP based on the RPi MAC Address, or you can directly set a static IP in the RPi(why didn't you do this in the first place?)

Comment: @Alex I tried searching around but didn't find any option to delete the leave. I had no idea that I could set a static IP in the RPi itself.... Why didn't I think of that. But that's just for the Pi. What about any other device that may connect to the router?

Comment: The other devices will get IP addresses from the router's DHCP server.